# Eclipse Java get path program

Tags: java, eclipse, path

I tried a program to get file name & path, but the problem is at: `dPath = Path.get(path);`

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Ch9_4_4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String file = "Ch9_4_3.java";
        String path = "temp2";
        Path fPath, dPath;
        fPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(".", file);
        dPath = Path.get(path);
        System.out.println(fPath.getFileName());
        System.out.println("temp2 is absolute path: "+dPath.isAbsolute());

        BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(fPath, BasicFileAttributes.class);
        if (Files.exists(fPath)) {
            System.out.println("Directory: " + attr.isDirectory());
            System.out.println("File: " + attr.isRegularFile());
            System.out.println("Create date: " + attr.creationTime());
            System.out.println("Size: " + attr.size());
        }
        else System.out.println("[" + fPath + "] does not exist!");

        Files.createDirectory(dPath);
        System.out.println("[" + dPath + "] directory is created!");
    }
}
```

I get the following Error message:

> The method get(String) is undefined for the type Path

Comment: `Paths` class contains `get` Method actually.. Not `Path`

Comment: This is not a forum where you can change the question to invalidate the existing (and accepted) answers. If you have a new problem, then create a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be Paths and not Path. Paths is the class that contains get() to convert a String to Path.

Comment: Yes, then I get another problem: 
`at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Unknown Source)`

Comment: Can you please paste the stacktrace? It would be difficult to identify the root cause otherwise. Best guess: file does not exist

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at wrong class i.e Path instead of Paths. Look at [Paths Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get(java.net.URI)) which has get method